# jQuery UI accordion on change ready handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, accordion

Is it possible to handle the event when I click on an accordion tab and the animation completes (not before nor during the animation) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [activate](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#event-activate) event is triggered after the animation has completed:

```
$("#yourElement").accordion({
    activate: function(event, ui) {
        // Animation is complete, do something...
    }
});
```

Comment: Are all animations complete, or just this single panel's ?

Comment: After both the original and the new panel's animations complete, I think.